# Dialogflow Messenger List Response Type Issue

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

I am using Dialogflow Messenger's `list response type` for a list of 8 services people can select from.

Can Dialogflow not handle more than 3 clicks in the list?

**Click service 1:** fires fine.

**Click service 2:** fires fine.

**Click service 3** or after that: "I don't understand."

However, people can type in the service and the bot responds just fine. Or people can click 1 service, ask the question again and select a different service and the bot responds fine. But we want people to be able to click all the services in the whole list.

[image]

Code used:

```js
{
  "richContent": [
    [
      {
        "type": "list",
        "event": {
          "parameters": {},
          "name": "Fire-Application-Development-Intent",
          "languageCode": ""
        },
        "title": "Application Development"
      },
      {
        "title": "Business Intelligence",
        "event": {
          "name": "Fire-Business-Intelligence-Intent",
          "languageCode": "",
          "parameters": {}
        },
        "type": "list"
      },
      {
        "type": "list",
        "title": "Digital Assistants (AI)",
        "event": {
          "parameters": {},
          "languageCode": "",
          "name": "Fire-Digital-Assistants-Intent"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "list",
        "title": "Mobile Development",
        "event": {
          "languageCode": "",
          "parameters": {},
          "name": "Fire-Mobile-Development-Intent"
        }
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "languageCode": "",
          "parameters": {},
          "name": "Fire-Websites-Intent"
        },
        "title": "Websites",
        "type": "list"
      },
      {
        "type": "list",
        "title": "ChatBeacon",
        "event": {
          "name": "Fire-ChatBeacon-Intent",
          "languageCode": "",
          "parameters": {}
        }
      },
      {
        "title": "Asset Location Tracking",
        "event": {
          "languageCode": "",
          "parameters": {},
          "name": "Fire-Asset-Location-Tracking-Intent"
        },
        "type": "list"
      },
      {
        "event": {
          "name": "Fire-NRS-Forms-Intent",
          "languageCode": "",
          "parameters": {}
        },
        "type": "list",
        "title": "NRS Forms"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the output to properly visualize the behavior of your Dialogflow Messenger? Can you include the code used for this? Just so the community can easily reproduce your issue.

Comment: Hello, I updated the post with a screenshot and code. Thanks!